# How to update parameter group for a ElastiCache (redis) cluster via CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-elasticache

I would like to close idle db connections to redis. `timeout` parameter let's you do that and `CfnParametreGroup` seems to be the way for it.

But my Redis Cluster is created via `CfnReplicationGroup`. How can I associate `CfnParametreGroup` with `CfnReplicationGroup`? There seems to be no way from the docs.

Looking for guidance on what's the correct procedure to update parameters for redis cluster via CDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing the [`cacheParameterGroupName`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticache.CfnReplicationGroup.html#cacheparametergroupname) prop.

```
...
cacheParameterGroupName=myParameterGroup.ref,
...
```